# PHP fixed arrays of data...performance issues

Tags: php, arrays

I have a telephone area code to Time zone array of several hundred elements. Is this array built at run time or at compile time. 
John

Comment: Are you afraid this is causing performance issues?  If so, profile.  Don't guess.

Answer (score 0):

there is no "compile time" in php. Or better put, there's no interval between compile and run time in php. A script gets compiled and then executed immediately.

Array of several hundred elements is normally not a problem, but post an example what it looks like, perhaps there's a better way (e.g. database).

Comment: If you use APC, you can skip the recompilation step -- the compiled bytecode is cached in memory.